# Android user session and SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm currently working on an android application that fetches information in a webservice. Those informations are related to a user ( who has a numeric user ID ).

So basically, I do Volley requests on URLs like this one :
http://api.mydomain/user/items with a POST parameter which is the userID I want to retrieve items.
When the user first log in to my app, I actually store his user ID in the Shared Preferences. This is useful for two things :

- I can access his ID from anywhere in my application and therefore do Volley request with the current user ID.
- I also use it on the application Splashscreen ( I check if there is this value in the shared preferences file and if so, he doesnt have to log in again and he's redirected to the application main activity ).

When the user disconnects from the application, I clear the Shared Preferences file, so he will have to log in again next time he open the app.

So here are my problems :

- If a rooted user open the shared preferences file, he will be able to change the user ID, and so his identity.
- If i keep this operating mode, I can't store user settings preferences ( Enable notifications etc.. ), which is the purpose of the shared preferences file ( I believe ), because i clear it when user disconnects in order to ask him to log-in again next time.

So, as you may think, I have the feeling that it's not the right thing to do..

What is the best pratice to do what i want to do ?

- Keep some kind of "session", to avoid the user having to reconnect each time he launch the app.
- Store his user ID in a secure manner, to prevent a malicious user to change it.

Is there a way to encrypt those critical data ? Maybe shouldn't I use a numeric ID, but rather some kind of encrypted key, to make it more difficult to change ?
Are SharedPreferences really used to store user's settings ( Should'nt I rather store it in the database ? )

Thank you in advance for helping me and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

SharePreferences are used to store such information. I store the Auth token in sharedPref in one of my apps. Yes, if user has rooted the phone, the sharedpreference xml becomes directly accessible but that's something that user has to take care off (since rooting is normally not advisable and if rooted don't handover the phone to a programmer!)

Coming to your scenario, you are deleting the shared preference on app close (disconnect). Seems like you are simply using the shared preference in one app life cycle and not the entire lifecycle (from install to uninstall). You can be better off by using a **singleton** class here. Singleton class will have one instance per life cycle and you can set the userId and get it from anywhere in the applifecycle!! :

```
Class mySingletonClass{

private String userID;
privat static mySingletonClass instance;

public static getInstance()
{

if(instance==null)  instance = new mySingletonClass();

return instance;

}


//getter setter for userID

}
```

to set UserID:

```
 mySingletonClass.getInstance().setUserID(String);
```

to ger UserID:

```
  mySngletonClass.getInstance().getUserID();
```

Now even if the phone is rooted, the userID is safely residing in heap memory !

If you do want to user SharedPreference for whole app life cycle (install to uninstall) and are worried about phone being rooted and userId being stolen, you can obfuscate the id before storing, but then again you need to store Key in shared preference too which defeats the purpose. Another way can be to store the key on server. Cracker can still snoop in the network calls and access the key but its a long shot.

Comment: First thank you for your answer !

I understand the use of a singleton in this case, and your example will be very helpful, but before storing the id in it, I need to retrieve it !

At the first login, this will be easy because user will enter username/password, so I can get his ID by requesting the right method in my webservice.

But what if he launches the app for the second time without disconnect before ? I'll not have the username/password to get the ID, and I don't want to store those data..
Can you give me more details on how do you achieve that with the "auth token" ( i don't get it..)

Comment: Welcome. I am guessing by disconnect you mean logout? Yes if user has not disconnected and come back to the app the userID should be stored locally in a shared preference. Security flaw with the root and retrieve can be overcome by encrypting and decrypting the userID with a key from server. Cant store the key in shared pref too as it will defeat the purpose of encrypting.